# Как достать содержимое p через JS?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добраться до контента в параграфе.

Если написать:

```html
let p = document.querySelector('.parag')
```

то выводится весь элемент с атрибутами.

Цель задачи, на следующем шаге, манипулировать с полученным значением document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let p = document.querySelector('.parag');
console.log(+p.textContent);
```

```html
<p class='parag'>123</p>
```